# Putting a Method in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, minecraft

So I want to make an array that has methods in it. For example:

```
public static void givePointBoost(){
points += 30};
```

or

```
public static void giveSword(){
Actions.giveItems(Items.diamond_sword);
Actions.givePotion(Potions.slowness);};
```

As you can see, both of these methods are voids. What I want to do is have an array that has all these voids in it so that I can pick a random method out of it later on. But I can't put it into an array because It says that I can't have an array of voids. When I try to make it an array of objects, It says that it can't switch from object to void. So my question is:

**How do you get methods inside of Arrays?**

Comment: Read about [Lambda Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions).

Comment: Java doesn't support putting methods into arrays. However, it can put objects into arrays. You can define an interface that has only one method, and put objects implementing that interface in an array

Comment: You Cant. However you can create a functional interface and then use lambdas to populate the array. Then you can create a reference to the interface and assign it to a random implementation from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's sort things out.
Arrays in Java can only contain objects or primitives.
Collections in Java can only contain objects.
What you're looking for is called a Command Pattern.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm

You'll have a list of objects, each of them with single method, let's say "execute". With polymorphism, each of this objects will do something different.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CommandPatternExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        commands.add(new GiveBoostCmmand("knight"));
        commands.add(new GiveItemCommand("sword", "knight"));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            commands.get((int)(Math.random() * commands.size())).execute();
        }


    }

    public interface Command {
        void execute();
    }

    static class GiveBoostCmmand implements Command {
        private String targetName;

        public GiveBoostCmmand(String targetName) {
            this.targetName = targetName;
        }

        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("Boosting " + this.targetName);
        }
    }

    static class GiveItemCommand implements Command {

        private String itemName;
        private String targetName;

        public GiveItemCommand(String itemName, String targetName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.targetName= targetName;
        }

        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("Giving " + this.itemName + " to " + this.targetName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, It gives me an error on the .add part of the command. It says, "Syntax error on token. Misplaced Constructs. Syntax error on add. Equals expected after this token." I tried doing both of these things, and more errors just came. Also, am I supposed to be importing classes from java.util?

Comment: I updated my answer with a full example, including imports.

Comment: Why does the computer not let me make a class static?

Comment: This is just an example. In reality, put each class into a separate file. Then you won't need static classes.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you do not have delegates or function pointers, which you can store in collections or arrays like objects, so you have to employ the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) to achieve this. Basically, you wrap a method in an object that you pass on. The receiver can then access the method via the object.

- Create a command interface:

  ```
  interface ICommand {
      public void execute();
  }
  ```
- Wrap a method (or multiple) in a class via inheritance...

  ```
  class SpecificCommand implements ICommand {
      public void execute() {
          // Do something...
      }
  }
  ```
- ...or wrap existing methods directly in an anonymous class:

  ```
  class SomeClass {

      private void someMethod(int someValue) {
          // Some stuff...
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          List<ICommand> commands = new ArrayList<>();

          // Do something...


          // Add command directly
          ICommand command = new ICommand() {
              @Override
              public void execute() {
                  someMethod(42);
              }
          }

          // Do something....

      }
  }
  ```
- Call the commands from the list in a loop (or single):

  ```
  for (ICommand command : commands) {
      command.execute();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say you want the result of the method to be added to the array?

As far as i know, i don't think you can put a method inside an array.

What you could do is create an interface, and provide implementations and then add those objects to an array. That way you could pick a random object and call the method defined in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The main question is Why do you need methods in an array?

The other solutions using the Command pattern are a great solution. But seeing your code I believe that you also should put that pattern in a specialized class whose purpose will be to initialize the pool of possible actions and select one at random when you need to.

Which would translate to the following UML

```
|RandomActionCaller      |
|------------------------|
|- List<Command> commands|
|------------------------|
|+ selectRandomEffect()  |
```

In the constructor you prepare the basic list of possible outcome, please refer to the other answers about the Command pattern. Maybe also add a method to add more commands to the list of commands from the outside of the class, this can be usefull.

The select random effect method would only select a random number between 0 and commands.size()-1, get the command instance and execute it. If you need to execute it somewhere else in your code just return it from the select random effect method.

Comment: Don't answer a question by proposing a solution to a question the OP didn't ask for. You should add this as a comment to the question. I realize you have the best intentions and you are fairly new to SO, so I won't downvote it =). You should consider deleting this answer though.

Comment: I'd have loved to add this as a comment but I can't with my reputation, I understand why there is this limitation but it's hindering my ability to help OPs at time like this one.

Comment: hmm... I like this idea. Can you please explain more about this?

Comment: After reading other solution proposed the Command pattern is indeed a great solution for you. However I'd embed it in a class like the one I've just described. I'll edit my answer to reflect the changes